# Phantom js picking an element from external site

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, monitoring, detection

I have a Phantom JS script, that monitors some external pages. Basically it just obtains status from this pages like this (typescript code):

```
const status: string = await page.evaluate(function() {
      return document.getElementsByClassName("status-containing-element")[0].innerHTML;
});
```

In some cases this element may not be displayed on site, then my script assume that site is currently unavailable. The problem is, if **status-containing-element** class name will be changed, my script will always think, that site is unavailable until I notice, that class name is changed. As a solution I tried to take page screenshot with phantom and checking parts of it to determine page status, but this seems like an overhead for me.

Is there any better/common way how to avoid such problems, e.g. automatically detect site structure change or smth like that?

Comment: Can't you just do a HTTP Request for this external site and check the HTTP Status? Or maybe they have an open API that makes it easier.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Unfortunately these sites don't have public api and i can't just do http request for this, because there may be many different statuses which are being rendered with js.

Comment: Ah, got it. I think there is no magic way to detect HTML structure changes, that's why we have APIs, to provide a reliable way to get data. Of course, you could check if a container element still exist.

Comment: The problem is that it may not exist for some period of time and it's part of site behavior. but anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why can't you just check if the site is down by grabbing the page title?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss as I already explained earlier in comments to this question, site can have more than 2 statuses, and as they are rendered with JS, only way i get them is actually loading page and getting status element.

Comment: you are trying to test two things in one check, why not separate them, first check the page response, `does it at least have a body` and then check for the status, if there is no body, then show site down error or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to class name, or instead of it, I would suggest querying for a specific selector using `querySelector()`. Usually the class name can change, while the general page structure remains the same. For example, consider something like that:

```
document.querySelector('#container > div > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > span > a');
```

To see what is the selector that represents your element, you can use Chrome Developer Tools: find it in "Elements" menu (right click -> Inspect), right click its code, Copy -> Selector. Then you can filter the class names if they change frequently to leave only the structure.

Note also that in your code you retrieve multiple elements and then take the first one (`[0]`), while `querySelector()` will return a single item. If you need all selectors, use `querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: Well, I would disagree about "Usually the class name can change, while the general page structure remains the same." statement. Anyway, thanks for another option.

Comment: @Max, I saw that while scraping websites, you can try both queries and see if it performs better than class only. You cannot defend your code from all the 3rd party changes anyway.

Comment: I agree here, but I'm looking for more or less change proof solution. Your answer doesn't seem any batter for me than taking page screenshot and then parsing it.